# :NET C#, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, .net, cors, postman

I have a problem running service I tried to develop. When I run it, I can execute it normally in Swagger, but it doesn't work when I try to use Postman or when I created a simple HTML page that calls fatch. I am using .NET 6.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/Exercises").then((result) => {console.log('result', result)});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Postman I tried to turn off certificates and I tried to add CORS to my application. Below is my code that I'm running. Can someone please help me out.
Program.cs

```
using VajeService.Data;
using VajeService.Interfaces;
using VajeService.Repositories;
using DotNetEnv;

Env.Load();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<MongoDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExerciseRepository, ExerciseRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
// Dodajanje CORS konfiguracije
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            );
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();


app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Sample of controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using VajeService.Interfaces;
using VajeService.Models;

namespace VajeService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExercisesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IExerciseRepository _exerciseRepository;

        public ExercisesController(IExerciseRepository exerciseRepository)
        {
            _exerciseRepository = exerciseRepository;
        }

        // Pridobivanje vseh vaj
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableCors("MyCorsPolicy")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Exercise>>> GetAllExercises()
        {
            var exercises = await _exerciseRepository.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(exercises);
        }
```

Comment: Hello Lonza, welcome to the Stack Overflow. In the given code you are not using any of the action methods in your fetch API call. `fetch("http://localhost:5000/Exercises")`. Can you please try calling any of the action methods rather than just calling the controller?
Also can you please provide the error status and message that the Postman is giving to you? Thanks.